# Ubuntu 12.04 refuses to work with GTX 550 Ti

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics

Ubuntu installation would not work with my GTX 550 ti, so I pulled it out and installed ubuntu just fine using my motherboards onboard graphics. But now I dont know how to get ubuntu to work with my 550 ti. I tried just plugging it back in with the pc on, but then the monitor will not display anything. I tried rebooting with the gfx card in but then ubuntu gets stuck on the purple screen. I have no idea what to do. please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold shift at boot, then do recovery, then normal boot.

Comment: It might be best if you could explain what you mean by do recovery--maybe with some steps to take, or with a link to another askubuntu question if that has already been covered. Thanks for your post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on a phone right now, will post when on mah pc.